# how to import sas datetime in the following format

Tags: sas

I am trying to load a csv file contain a date-time variable. The variable looks like the following

```
datetime
2008-10-08T07:06:08.248635000Z
2008-10-08T07:06:09.613897000Z
2008-10-08T07:06:28.217422000Z
2008-10-08T07:07:53.461926000Z
2008-10-27T16:10:49.189132000Z
```

I tried format `time18.3`, but because there is a character `T` after the date and character `Z` after the time, so the importing is not successful. Could anyone teach me how to load this data please.

Comment: Post anything you've tried. Have you checked the INFORMATs listed in the documentation - this is an ISO 8601 formatted date or similar enough or ANYDTDTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's `B8601DZw.d` format; so you can use `B8601DZ30.` I believe.

```
  data _null_;
    dt_char='2008-10-08T07:06:08.248635000Z';
    dt_num = input(dt_char,B8601DZ30.);
    put dt_num= datetime.;
  run;
```